Preload WASM Module when instantiating another one in Javascript
What is the equivilant of this cmd in JS:
wasmtime run --preload mod0=mod0.wat --invoke 'hello' hello.wasm
The underlying code errors out:
const importObject = {
  imports: {
    imported_func: arg => {
      console.log(arg);
    }
  }
};

fetch("hello.wasm").then(response =>
  response.arrayBuffer()
  ).then(bytes =>
    WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, importObject)
  ).then(result => {
    result.instance.exports.hello();
 });

// Error

Import #0 module="mod0" error: module is not an object or function

